# Skip particular value from $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following sample php code for method types and documents like this-

```
 <?php 
    $arrTestData = [ 
                  1 => [
                     'id' => '1',
                     'name' => 'Written'
                  ],
                  2 => [
                    'id' => '2',
                    'name' => 'Verbal'
                  ]
    ];
    $arrDocuments = [ 
                   1=> [
                      'file_id' => '1',
                      'file_name' => 'TestDoc.pdf'
                   ],
                   2=> [
                       'file_id' => '2',
                       'file_name' => 'pranav.pdf'
                  ]
    ];
   $arrVariable = json_encode( $arrTestData );
  $arrDocuments = json_encode( $arrDocuments );?>
```

I passed json_encode data to javascript. But I want to check if document is present then only show document dropdown in dynamically created row. Also to skip WRITTEN type from first dropdown. Js code looks like -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var response = '<?php echo $arrVariable; ?>';
var docs = '<?php echo $arrDocuments; ?>';
data = $.parseJSON(response);
doc = $.parseJSON(docs);

var counter = 1;
var newRow = $("<tbody>");
$('.addNotice').on('click',function() {
        var strHtml = "";
        strHtml += "<tr class=row" + counter + " bRow><td class=align-center border-right>" + counter + "</td>";
        strHtml += "<td><select class=form-select wide3 js-method name=violation_template_notices[" + counter + "][violation_warning_type_id] value=''>";
        $.each(data,function(key,value) {
            strHtml += "<option value="+ value.id +">"+ value.name +"</option>";
        });
        strHtml += "</select></td><td><select class=form-select wide3 js-method name=violation_template_notices[" + counter + "][document_id] value=''>";
        $.each(doc,function(key,value) {
            strHtml += "<option value="+ value.file_id +">"+ value.file_name +"</option>";
        });
        strHtml += "</select></td>";
        strHtml += "<td>--</td>";
        strHtml += "<td>--</td>";
        strHtml +="</tr>";
        counter++;
        newRow.append(strHtml);
        $("table").append(newRow);
    });
});
```

**I try to use if(doc.length == 0 ) { // hide dropdown } but it fails for first dropdown.**

Comment: You can check for whatever you want inside `each`; it's not at all clear what the issue is. Why would `doc.length` ever be zero? Don't you want to check for a value in one of the array's entries?

Comment: Have you the JSON inside your js variables ?

Comment: No need to use `JSON.parse()`. Just remove the quotes that wrap the php output and javascript will read as array

Comment: @charlietfl If removed quotes as you suggest then it gives me error in console - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Comment: What does the generated source look like in browser? Is this JS in a js file or in php file? that error makes me think it is in a js file and php doesn't compile js files

Comment: @charlietfl yes your solution works a little bit. it treated as an array. now need to skip "written" value from the first dropdown in js.

Answer (score 0):

This will skip the first item in the `doc` json. Change the index  at `(key !== index)` to select the item you want to skip.

```
if (doc.length) {
    strHtml += "<select class=form-select wide3 js-method name=violation_template_notices[" + counter + "][document_id] value=''>";
    $.each(doc,function(key,value) {
          if (key !== 0) strHtml += "<option value="+ value.file_id +">"+ value.file_name +"</option>";
    });
    strHtml += "</select>";
} else {
    strHtml += "<select class=empty></select>";
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it shows the dropdown. Is it possible to hide dropdown rather than to show the empty dropdown?

Comment: You can do it with CSS by adding a class when it's empty or just avoid creating the element with JS. I would only hide it since it might be needed for another functionality. I updated the answer to include this solution